# how to use array_push with key value in a for loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use array_push with key value pair in a for loop in php but I'm not getting anything in there, I only get 2 keys with no values, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong,

any help would be appreciated.

```
$totalItems = $dataArray["totalItemsCount"];
$linkNamesTaken = array();
for($i=0; $i<$totalItems; $i++) {
   array_push($linkNamesTaken[$dataArray["data"][$i]["subMediaType"]], $dataArray["data"][$i]["code"]);
}

print_r($linkNamesTaken);
```

I'm only getting

```
 [Track] => 
 [Album] =>
```

I'm expecting something like

```
[Track] => LSD-ThundercloudswithSiaDiploLabrinth-Single
[Album] => DuaLipa-ElectricitywithDuaLipa-Album
```

the dataArray contains data like the following

```
{"totalItemsCount": 7,
 "data": [
    {
        "id": "366eff50-d6e2-4038-a091-4b84849c7e9e",
        "url": "https://APItestboard.lnk.to/GeorgeEzra-Shotgun-Single",
        "code": "GeorgeEzra-Shotgun-Single",
        "subMediaType": "Track"
    },
   ... 6 more items here like above

 ]
}
```

Comment: Please show us what all those variables contain or it's literally impossible for us to know what's going on. You also need to show us the expected result.

Comment: show us your `$totalItems`

Comment: Please see the edited question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with key has `subMediaType` & value as `code` in your `linkNamesTaken` array

```
$linkNamesTaken = array();
foreach($dataArray['data'] as $k1 => $v1) { //7 loop on key value pair
      $linkNamesTaken[$v1['subMediaType']] = $v1['code']; // hopefully key value should be unique.
}

print_r($linkNamesTaken);
```

**O/P**

```
Array
(
    [Track] => GeorgeEzra-Shotgun-Single
    [New Track] => GeorgeEzra-Shotgun-Double
)
```

**EDIT** : see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#108118

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
$totalItems = $dataArray["totalItemsCount"];
$linkNamesTaken = array();
foreach($totalItems as $key => $value) {
   foreach($value['data'] as $key2 => $value2) {
       $linkNamesTaken[]['subMediaType'] = $value2['subMediaType'];
       $linkNamesTaken[]['code'] = $value2['code'];
   }
}
```

Comment: $totalItems is only a number, it doesn't have key value pair. I need to get the subMediaType as key and code as value and push them into the $linkNamesTaken array.